# HIBERNATE - JPA how can I pass a String containing an underscore to a CriteriaBuilder query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Unfortunately I'm not authorized to show any code. Also I'm sorry if I'm not giving enough info, this is my first time asking a question on this website. Please let me know if there's more you need to know.

I have a CriteriaBuilder query that sorts via Pageable.
The sorting method as of right now sorts by entities' properties, however I want to sort by a field generated by a LISTAGG but every time I try to pass "col_12_0_" hibernate sees the underscore and only takes "col" as a value... How can I solve this?

I've tried using the .alias() method to generate the alias I want in the query but it seems like it's not working as CB always generates aliases such as "col_1_0_".

I've also tried setting the generation strategy as PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl but nothing changes.

Comment: Listagg is oracle specific query so you need to create native query

Comment: No I have already registered LISTAGG as a custom function and it's working just fine

I just need to be able to sort by alias rathern than attribute, and then be able to have hibernate accept a string with an underscore in it

Comment: Provide the code you have written. Like how you register LISTAGG and how you create the CriteriaBuilder etc

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide the code as per my NDA

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate ORM's JPA Criteria implementation, this is only possible as of version 6. It should work with HQL also in Hibernate 5 though.

If you must use JPA Criteria, you will have to introduce another custom function, e.g. `pass_through` which accepts a string and renders the unquoted string to SQL. Then you can use that to render "any" SQL fragments you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement this solution when I have time for refactoring!